# With ServiceStack 3.9.56 cannot find the namespace ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web

Tags: c#, servicestack

Using NuGet package manager I added the ServiceStack Clients package to a C# project.  I tried to add the namespace reference "using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web" to a class but the namespace isn't available.  I've removed the ServiceStack packages with NuGet, compiled the project and added them again, but the namespace ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web isn't found.
I have a separate project which uses ServiceStack 3.9.49 and the exact same NuGet packages [ID: ServiceStack.Text & ServiceStack.Common] and the namespace is available in that version.

Answer (score 3):

As this was a new project, I neglected to change the target framework from the client profile to the full/complete profile.  Once I made the change, and compiled the app, the namespace was then available.  Thanks.